# Unity crashes when I hit play

Tags: unity-game-engine

It started from yesterday. Each time I play my game in Unity Editor, after a minute, it crashes with this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmjD3.jpg)

```
Flatbuffers: Parser.Parse() failed at (1, 1) error: illegal charachters: <
```

I have no idea where Flatbuffers is in my project. But these are the plugins I have:

- Unity Mobile Notification
- FireBase
- Dotween
- TextMeshPro
- Admob

Note: When I build my game and play it on Android, there is no problem with it.

Note: The first one about the AudioSource isn't a problem. I know what's happening and have already fixed it. But I have no Idea about the second one. What should I do?

Comment: There should be a stack trace that will tell you where that code is called from or at least help you guess. Try clearing your player prefs.

Comment: an error isnt a crash. the fact you can see those errors show its not a crash .. unity go byebye when your code crashes :D  So you have an error. as Retired Ninja said, there will be a stack trace with those errors. if there isnt you should turn it back on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone faces the same issue: This is a problem with firebase. when the net is offline and it can't connect to google, the crash happens. And it only happens on Unity Playmode and won't affect the final app.

P.S: thanks for the answers. They guided me towards Stacktrace and helped me solve the problem.